# What is the best way to display a hierarchy of choices in an ASP.net Forms Application?

Tags: asp.net, hierarchy, web-controls

I am working on an ASP.net Forms Application that keeps track of information about different offices in an organization.  The offices are organized into a hierarchy.

Some users of the program will have access to certain information about all offices in the hierarchy.  Some users of the program will have access to only a small part of the hierarchy.

When a user browses for information they are authorized to see, I would like to present the user with a prompt to choose which office in the hierarchy they wish to see information from.

I want to accomplish the following:
 A) I want the user to be able to easily navigate the hierarchy of the organization to locate a specific office.
 B) I want the user to be able to navigate the hierarchy without refreshing the page.
 C) I want my interface to be able to handle a hierarchy at least four layers deep with less than 100 nodes.

I see that Microsoft includes a `TreeView` control in the standard collection of ASP web controls.  Would `Treeview` be the most appropriate tool for what I want to do, or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say with built in controls the Treeview is the way to go.

Here's a nice [tutorial](http://www.15seconds.com/issue/041117.htm) on how to use it.

Answer (score 2):

You could look at client-side JavaScript Tree libraries such as http://www.jstree.com/

Comment: Upvote for jquery/ajax instead of MS-ajax/postback.  Yeah, it's personal bias - but its based on the amount of pain each one has caused me in the past.  :)

Comment: Absolutely. I've tried several server-side controls in the past, but have found implementing JSTree with a .Net Web Service much easier... Here's an example: http://old.nabble.com/jQuery-plugin-jsTree-does-not-show-up-on-page.-td24190357.html

Answer (score 1):

The [asp.net treeview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d4fz6xk2(VS.80).aspx) would be an excellent place to start.

Enjoy!